# CPU at 100% all the time.

Tags: windows-7, windows

I took the big step and disabled all the resources and after rebooting the cpu returned to normal. While I proved the culprit was there I have no idea which one is the problem. Does anyone know which one is the problem?

Comment: The only thing you can really do is enable things one by one until the problem occurs again.

Comment: analyze the cpu usage with WPA/WPR: http://superuser.com/a/1066939/174557 (WIn10 WPT also works in Win7) and extend the stack of the process with the largest CPU usage

Comment: Try turning off just the Windows Update service.

Answer (score 0):

Enable half of your “resources” and reboot. Is your CPU at 100%? Then the culprit is in the half you enabled, if not it’s in the half not enabled. Enable half the resources in the half you know the culprit is in. Reboot. Now you know which quarter of the resources the culprit is in. Continue until there is only one resource enabled; that’s the culprit.

[See this article by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331796)