# Why is my CPU heavily loaded?

Tags: laptop, cpu

Idle CPU load ranges 30-80%, when performing any tasks - 100%. problem in linux and windows. The computer is not dusty, model acer ao722, fan is working. Sensor shows initial termperature - 57 C, idle temperature - 67 C. Also happens when I use Linux from USB stick (live image).

system monitor screenshot

[image: system monitor screenshot]

output of "top -b -n1":

```
top - 23:40:11 up 2 min,  2 users,  load average: 2,61, 1,42, 0,55
Tasks: 168 total,   3 running, 165 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 44,4 us, 12,6 sy,  6,0 ni, 30,1 id,  5,2 wa,  1,7 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   1770520 total,   702748 used,  1067772 free,    45836 buffers
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,        0 used,  2097148 free.   271824 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  862 root      20   0   30608   2452   1876 R  59,0  0,1   0:00.42 wpa_suppli+
 2174 root      20   0   33224   1492   1084 R   5,9  0,1   0:00.03 top
    1 root      20   0   33768   3128   1468 S   0,0  0,2   0:05.05 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.03 kworker/u8+
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0,0  0,0   0:01.49 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.28 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.31 rcuos/1
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuos/2
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuos/3
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/1
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/2
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/3
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.04 migration/0
   18 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/0
   19 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
   20 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 migration/1
   21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/1
   22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:+
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khelper
   25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 kdevtmpfs
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 netns
   27 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 writeback
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   29 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bioset
   30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u9+
   31 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kblockd
   32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ata_sff
   33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.08 khubd
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 md
   35 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq
   36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.16 kworker/1:1
   37 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.53 kworker/0:1
   38 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
   39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kswapd0
   40 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksmd
   41 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 khugepaged
   42 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 fsnotify_m+
   43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-k+
   44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 crypto
   56 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthrotld
   57 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u8+
   58 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 kworker/u8+
   77 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 deferwq
   78 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 charger_ma+
  125 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  126 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  127 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.10 usb-storage
  128 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u8+
  138 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.03 jbd2/sda5-8
  139 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ext4-rsv-c+
  263 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u9+
  265 root      20   0   19604    912    616 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.73 upstart-ud+
  271 root      20   0   51808   2012   1028 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.35 systemd-ud+
  426 message+  20   0   40280   2504   1008 S   0,0  0,1   0:01.06 dbus-daemon
  465 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 cfg80211
  466 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
  469 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:2
  506 syslog    20   0  255840   1264    840 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.09 rsyslogd
  512 root      20   0   19416   2020   1620 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.02 bluetoothd
  516 root      20   0   43448   1876   1504 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 systemd-lo+
  546 root      10 -10       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 krfcommd
  565 root      20   0   76852   3728   2644 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.05 cupsd
  568 avahi     20   0   32348   1656   1352 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.04 avahi-daem+
  572 avahi     20   0   32224    464    212 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 avahi-daem+
  574 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 wl_event_h+
  587 root      20   0   15540    752    324 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.26 upstart-fi+
  595 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kvm-irqfd-+
  596 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 hci0
  598 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 hci0
  599 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ttm_swap
  611 root      20   0   75352   3408   2512 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.03 cups-brows+
  714 root      20   0  330232   4424   3252 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.08 ModemManag+
  749 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u9+
  760 root      20   0  360840   8908   5256 S   0,0  0,5   0:00.34 NetworkMan+
  798 root      20   0  295832   5836   3724 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.44 polkitd
  813 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 hd-audio0
  822 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 hd-audio1
  870 root      20   0   15656   1032    420 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.12 upstart-so+
  977 root      20   0   24228    948    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
  981 root      20   0   24228    956    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
  986 root      20   0   24228    952    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
  988 root      20   0   24228    956    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
  991 root      20   0   24228    948    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
 1040 root      20   0   23656   1040    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 cron
 1045 root      20   0   19188    720    500 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.33 irqbalance
 1046 root      20   0    4368    720    540 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 acpid
 1047 kernoops  20   0   37144   1012    692 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 kerneloops
 1061 whoopsie  20   0  276740   4256   3028 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.02 whoopsie
 1072 root      20   0  292608   6404   3544 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.09 lightdm
 1090 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 iprt
 1093 root      20   0  302240   5120   4016 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.29 accounts-d+
 1178 root      20   0   24228    948    796 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 getty
 1189 root      20   0  242920  31484  16088 S   0,0  1,8   0:31.94 Xorg
 1195 root      20   0  168288   3696   2932 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.04 lightdm
 1198 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kauditd
 1213 user      20   0   44140   2332   1612 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.24 init
 1336 user      20   0   40800   2204    816 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.74 dbus-daemon
 1338 user      20   0   10616    312      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ssh-agent
 1345 user      20   0   26512   1184   1004 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 upstart-ev+
 1368 user      20   0   34996    704    400 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 upstart-fi+
 1371 user      20   0   26520    644    408 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.04 upstart-db+
 1372 user      20   0   26520    648    408 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.06 upstart-db+
 1413 user      20   0  367532   4388   3624 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.03 at-spi-bus+
 1420 user      20   0   39228   1872   1448 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.05 dbus-daemon
 1423 user      20   0  125020   3408   2804 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.05 at-spi2-re+
 1427 user      20   0  200852   3132   2532 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.08 gvfsd
 1437 user      20   0  360424   3920   3184 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.04 gvfsd-fuse
 1465 user      20   0    4444    680    572 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 sh
 1480 user      20   0  328572   9272   6344 S   0,0  0,5   0:00.30 xfce4-sess+
 1483 user      20   0   39456   2584   2056 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.12 xfconfd
 1487 user      20   0  326856   4648   3700 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.05 gnome-keyr+
 1490 user      20   0  171628  12548   8768 S   0,0  0,7   0:00.94 xfwm4
 1494 user      20   0  251844   7056   5488 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.11 Thunar
 1496 user      20   0  567452  16496  11096 S   0,0  0,9   0:00.84 xfce4-panel
 1497 user      20   0  690632  24500  15560 S   0,0  1,4   0:01.41 xfdesktop
 1498 user      20   0  350304   9096   6436 S   0,0  0,5   0:01.89 xfsettingsd
 1500 root      20   0  304944   4684   3632 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.33 upowerd
 1521 user      20   0  479020  14380  10372 S   0,0  0,8   0:00.59 panel-1-wh+
 1527 user      20   0  247120   7004   5184 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.20 xfce4-powe+
 1529 user      20   0  226836   7168   5652 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.07 light-lock+
 1533 user      20   0  762560  18532  12108 S   0,0  1,0   0:00.69 nm-applet
 1535 user      20   0  470812   9752   5988 S   0,0  0,6   0:00.13 zeitgeist-+
 1537 user      20   0  708304  16836  11920 S   0,0  1,0   0:00.71 update-not+
 1539 user      20   0  286748   7056   3936 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.10 indicator-+
 1544 user      20   0  257840  16376   7148 S   0,0  0,9   0:00.52 applet.py
 1547 user      39  19  305728  12256   6016 S   0,0  0,7   0:00.24 tumblerd
 1550 user      20   0  168528   3732   2476 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.01 xfce4-powe+
 1553 user      20   0  629780  31108  14504 S   0,0  1,8   0:00.91 blueman-ap+
 1559 user      20   0  226664   6680   5252 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.08 polkit-gno+
 1569 user      20   0  299780   4452   3620 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.09 indicator-+
 1581 user      20   0  158592   7356   5724 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.11 panel-4-sy+
 1588 user      20   0  565960  17640  11832 S   0,0  1,0   0:00.73 panel-5-in+
 1600 user      20   0  331276   3736   2956 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.13 zeitgeist-+
 1607 user      20   0  748504 105624  55224 S   0,0  6,0   0:27.81 update-man+
 1611 user      20   0  484308  15288   8884 S   0,0  0,9   0:03.23 xfce4-xkb-+
 1619 user      20   0  168100   9492   7464 S   0,0  0,5   0:00.14 panel-15-a+
 1648 user      20   0  233188   5580   4580 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.12 zeitgeist-+
 1653 user       9 -11  445444   6020   3872 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.19 pulseaudio
 1656 user      20   0  304808   6524   3588 S   0,0  0,4   0:04.03 xfce4-volu+
 1658 rtkit     21   1  168916   1308   1084 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.02 rtkit-daem+
 1659 user      20   0  359732  13656   9828 S   0,0  0,8   0:00.55 xfce4-noti+
 1701 user      20   0   15624    612    520 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 cat
 1737 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:2
 1793 user      20   0  315788   5956   4088 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.16 gvfs-udisk+
 1796 root      20   0  386292   8276   4200 S   0,0  0,5   0:00.43 udisksd
 1808 user      20   0  216652   3404   2648 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.06 gvfs-gphot+
 1814 user      20   0  290172   3384   2720 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.05 gvfs-afc-v+
 1819 user      20   0  204488   2844   2276 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.05 gvfs-mtp-v+
 1829 user      20   0   35444   1864   1428 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.06 init
 1832 user      20   0  369316   6084   3328 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.03 indicator-+
 1837 user      20   0  573472   6828   5076 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.16 indicator-+
 1839 user      20   0  378404   6472   3604 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.06 gvfsd-trash
 1889 user      20   0   61320   2508   2036 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.02 gconfd-2
 1974 user      20   0   62328   2600   2144 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.03 obex-data-+
 1978 user      20   0  178176   2620   2152 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.06 dconf-serv+
 2027 root      25   5  294428  86368  45300 S   0,0  4,9   0:07.04 aptd
 2047 user      20   0  621772  15740  11172 S   0,0  0,9   0:00.74 xfce4-term+
 2051 user      20   0   14824    800    648 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 gnome-pty-+
 2052 user      20   0   31020   3700   1692 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.13 bash
 2134 root      20   0   75688   2396   1768 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.05 sudo
 2145 root      20   0   31052   3756   1696 S   0,0  0,2   0:00.13 bash
```

output of "/proc/cpuinfo":

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 20
model       : 2
model name  : AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x5000101
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor ssse3 cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ibs skinit wdt arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
bogomips    : 1994.99
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 20
model       : 2
model name  : AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x5000101
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor ssse3 cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ibs skinit wdt arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
bogomips    : 1994.99
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
```

Comment: We need more information. The fact this happens on two entirely different operating systems designed significantly different indicates a hardware problem.  I would replace the HDD.

Comment: So it’s Linux we’re talking about. Please post the output of `top -b -n1`. And, while we˚re at it, the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` might also be of interest.

Comment: I added what you asked

Comment: This is a good start. `wpa_supplicant` is related to wireless networking, and in the `top` output you showed it is consuming 59% of the CPU time. **There's your problem,** at least at that moment. I'd run `top` for a while and keep an eye on that one; is that a fluke and it just happened to be consuming a lot of CPU right then and there, or is there actually something going on here?

Comment: Now there is different process uses 59%.  Processes are changed. May be it's problem of HDD like Ramhound said, because when I have opened filesystems tab it shows only one partition (but it not true) ?

Comment: Although there is the same problem when I used a live image with Linux.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of Task Manager, sorted by CPU usage?

Comment: I had [a problem](http://superuser.com/questions/268612/cpu-usage-shoots-to-50-and-stays-there-until-suspended) where my Sony Vista (dual CPU) would go to 50% and stay there.  Finally traced it to the WiFi adapter which, *when turned off*, would produce a steady CPU interrupt, totally tying up one processor.  The time would be "charged" to random programs or to none at all.  Simply leaving the WiFi adapter turned on fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had disabled wifi hardware switch on notebook and enabling (you can disable it after that and heavy cpu usage won't come back again) removed heavy cpu usage.

Comment: Yeah, I had essentially the [same problem](http://superuser.com/questions/268612/cpu-usage-shoots-to-50-and-stays-there-until-suspended).